# Coldfusion - how to convert one structure to an array

Tags: arrays, coldfusion, structure, coldfusion-9

I am helping a friend with a Coldfusion issue, I am just having difficulty with a simple problem. We are trying to obtain the column names coming from a SQL table and the way we do that is by doing the following:

Now we are trying to get the same info but from an Array of Structures (see screen shot attached here).

[image]

```
    <cfdump var="#ApiData#">
    <cfset numColumns = StructCount(ApiData[1])>
    <cfdump var="#numColumns#">
    <cfdump var="#ApiData[1].Created#">
    <cfabort>

    <cfloop from="1" to="#numColumns#" index="i">   
        <cfset ColumnNames = ?how do I create an array of columns here?
    </cfloop>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you want an array of `["Created", "CreatedBy", etc]` ?

That's just:

```
structKeyArray(nameOfStruct);
```

You don't need the loop.

Docs: [`structKeyArray()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f00.html)

Comment: just what I needed thank you! I did the following:    <cfset ColumnNames  = structKeyArray(ApiData[1])>

Comment: the only problem now is that I am trying to loop through the columns to print out the values but I only know how to print out them individually such as "#ApiData[i].Created#", "#ApiData[i].Name#", etc if you have any idea let me know, otherwise thanks a lot!!!

Comment: You may want to post that as a separate question, but the short answer is you want to put your code in `<cfoutput>` tags